# I'm learning Java and I am using H2 database through JDBC And It is not working. It says that the operation it is not permitted

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

Error code:

```
IO Exception: "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/Franco/Desktop/h2: Operation not permitted"; "/Users/Franco/Desktop/h2"
IO Exception: "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/Franco/Desktop/h2: Operation not permitted"; "/Users/Franco/Desktop/h2" [90031-212] 90031/90031])
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mcVi.png)

Code from the IDE:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:"+ "/Users/Franco/Desktop/h2/bin", "root", "myPassword");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        //Código para crear una tabla. Elimina la tabla si esta ya existe y la
        //vuelve a crear
        String createSql = """
                DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST;
                CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(255));
                INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(1, 'Hello');
                INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(2, 'World');
                """;
        stmt.execute(createSql);

        //Codigo para consultar todos los registros de la tabla TEST
        String sql = "select * from TEST";
        ResultSet rd = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        //Código para recorrer el resultado de la consulta
        while(rd.next()) {
            System.out.println(rd.getInt(1) + rd.getString(2));
        }
        con.close();
    }
}
```

I think it might be an access request.
I have a Mac with macOS Ventura 13.2.1

Comment: Hi&welcome! 1. Db (file) url should be a file (not a directory!) ..in an existing directory. See also: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url ..and 2. There seem to be permission issues on that folder/your OS

Comment: (1. Actually it is `/path/to/<db_name>`, where in `path/to`(accessible, writable, directory!) multiple files with "db_name" prefix *should* be created;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:"+ "~/h2", "root", "myPassword");
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like the following code in my site

```
Connection c = drm.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:"+ "/binlbr", "admin", "pass");
```

Comment: Ok. It opens but Hello World is not there